# How to select text file and read file's content to string React Native

Tags: react-native

I have just picked up React Native to develop a new mobile app. Unfortunately I ran into a few problems with using it to access on-device-files for use with my program. Basically I was looking for a way to let the user select a text file then read said text file to a String and then use string manipulation to extract my data. After a while afternoon of digging around on Google I've found react-native-fs and react-native-document-select, but the first one seems to only be able to read files on my device, and I'm not sure how to pass the file path from the second one to the first one. Any suggestions would be awesome

Comment: have you tried using react-native-fs?

Comment: Yes I have listed that in the post